# How to connect to MongoDB hosted on Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I just created a MongoDB instance on Google Cloud.
I have been using mLab for my purpose and I was able to connect to that DB using IPAddress: PORT and user/password combination.

How to connect to MongoDB instance using IP Address and port number? Where can I find these details in my VM Instance?

I also want to connect to same DB through my NodeJS app using mongoose. How can I do that?

Comment: The link gives basic setup using mlab instance. The question is about about MongoDB instance on Google Cloud.
Thanks for the tips about searching.

Comment: connect via another VM or via external client?
which client you want to connect (python, nodejs, mongoclient)